# Почему не находит содержимое дополнительного поля? wordpress

Tags: wordpress

С помощью дополнительных полей загружаю файл на сервер.
Дополнительные поля прикручены с странице "Прайс-лист". На ней добавляю в цикле:

```
<a class="button button1" href="<?php echo get_field( 'price_file_' . $i )['url']?>" download>Скачать прайс-лист</a>
```

Все работает.

На главной тоже есть ссылки на скачку прайса и не работает. Код аналогичный, вот такой:

```
<a class="button1 index-offer__button" href="<?php echo get_field( 'price_file_' . $i )['url'] ?>" download>Скачать полный прайс-лист</a>
```

атрибут `href` не заполняется. Почему? Как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно указать ID страницы с прайсом

```
<a class="button1 index-offer__button" href="<?php echo get_field( 'price_file_' . $i, ID_страницы )['url'] ?>" download>Скачать полный прайс-лист</a>
```

Подробнее в [документации](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/).